# how to set width for item inside flex overflown

Tags: css

I got code like this

```css
.divA {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.epi {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="divA">
  <div class="epi">
    <h1>dsds</h1>
    <p>sdsds</p>
    <img src="img/heart.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="epi">
    <h1>dsds</h1>
    <p>sdsds</p>
    <img src="img/heart.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="epi">
    <h1>dsds</h1>
    <p>sdsds</p>
    <img src="img/heart.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="epi">
    <h1>dsds</h1>
    <p>sdsds</p>
    <img src="img/heart.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting this

[image]

But I'm getting this

[image]

I want item in .divA has the width of 50% of .divA

Comment: add `flex-shrink:0` to the elements

Comment: thanks very much..

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Since you don't want it to wrap, but scroll horizontally, you can put it as `overflow-x: scroll;`

```css
.divA {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.epi {
  min-width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="divA">
  <div class="epi">
    <h1>dsds</h1>
    <p>sdsds</p>
    <img src="img/heart.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="epi">
    <h1>dsds</h1>
    <p>sdsds</p>
    <img src="img/heart.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="epi">
    <h1>dsds</h1>
    <p>sdsds</p>
    <img src="img/heart.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="epi">
    <h1>dsds</h1>
    <p>sdsds</p>
    <img src="img/heart.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-wrap wil break the down the line. I want all item on the same line. and scrollable horizontally.

Comment: I've edited my answer. It should suit your purpose now.